# Opening Windows Explorer to Specific Path in PyQt properly

Tags: python, pyqt, explorer

I'm trying to open a specific folder from my PyQt program. I know I could've used webbrowser module
like this

```
import webbrowser, os
path="C:/Users"
webbrowser.open(os.path.realpath(path))
```

or I could've used os.startfile module like this

```
import os
path = "C:/Users"
path = os.path.realpath(path)
os.startfile(path)
```

or subprocess which isn't recommended on Qt platform. so I wonder how could you do it on PyQt properly (maybe using QProcess?). I don't want to open file or folder dialog because I just want to open the folder without doing anything with it. also, I want to save time for a future update on a different OS than Windows, so I didn't have to change this part. is it possible?. many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Qt cross-platform solution is to use [`QDesktopServices::openUrl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl):

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

path = "C:/Users"
fullpath = os.path.realpath(path)

if not QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)):
    print("failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use QProcess to open explorer on specific path without additional module (e.g webbrowser). I only need platform module to determine which platform the program is running, like this

```
    self.path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    self.pathOutput = os.path.join(self.path, "output")

def open_explorer(self):
    self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        self._process.start("explorer",[os.path.realpath(self.pathOutput)])
    elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
        self._process.start("open",[os.path.realpath(self.pathOutput)])
```